# Ruby: What is the meaning of "variable.property!" syntax?

Tags: ruby, syntax, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

I'm analyzing a block of code written in ruby.
I don't know the language and I need to understand an operation.

```
def restore
  m = ObjectName.where(prop: User.where(email: 'admin@email.com').first.element_id).last
  m.todo!
  m.waiting!
  ...
end
```

what "m.todo!" and "m.waiting!" are doing?
I cannot understand if it is assigning a "true" value or a value that is the opposite of the current one like: m.todo = !m.todo

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

`!` and `?` are valid parts of a method name in Ruby. They don't have any special meaning, though `!` is conventionally used for mutative or destructive actions, and `?` is conventionally used for predicate methods.

In this example, there are two methods named `todo!` and `waiting!` being called - nothing fancier. If I had to guess, those are methods which simply perform a combined "update a state variable and save" operation (hence, mutative).

Comment: In Rails `!` also means "raises exceptions" in contrast to the non-`!` which may return `nil`.

Comment: user2750691, "mutative or destructive actions" (if not clear) means that the method changes the value of its receiver, here the object held by the variable `m`. For example, suppose `m = [1,2]`. Then (no '!'): `m.map { |x| x+1 } #=> [2,3]`, after which, `m #=> [1,2]`. By contrast, `m.map! { |x| x+1 } #=> [2,3]`, after which, `m #=> [2,3]`. The exclamation mark at the end of a method name tells the reader that the method does something that may be "dangerous". For core methods (except for a handful), that means it mutates it's receiver, a practice generally frowned upon by some coders.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: `m.clear` also mutates its receiver, though, and does not have a bang. The rule is that the bang marks the "more surprising" of a pair of methods. If there is no second method, there is no bang.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, the family of `replace` methods is another example, but I didn't say that all methods that mutate their receiver have a bang (though your point is worthwhile). I've seen references to both the adjectives "dangerous" and "surprising", but am not aware that either has any official status.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I’ll try to go deeper into the code, however I cannot find these methods in the model. It seems these are properties (boolean) that comes from the dto.

Answer (score -1):

In Ruby, `foo.bar` is the syntax for a *message send*. It will first evaluate the expression `foo` (which is either dereferencing a local variable or a receiverless message send to the implicit receiver `self`) and then send the message `bar` to the resulting object.

Once you know what message send in Ruby looks like, it is easy to see what `m.todo!` does: It will first evaluate the expression `m` (which is either dereferencing a local variable or a receiverless message send to the implicit receiver `self`) and then send the message `todo!` to the resulting object.

Method names ending in `!` are typically used to mark the "more surprising" of a pair of methods. So, if you have *two* Methods, both of which do similar things, then the one with the bang at the end is the "more surprising" one. A good example are [`Process::exit`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Process.html#method-c-exit) and [`Process::exit!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Process.html#method-c-exit-21). Both exit the currently running Ruby process, but the "normal" version (i.e. the one without the bang) runs the exit handlers normally, whereas the "surprising" Version exits immediately *without* running the exit handlers.

Note: there seems to be a lot of misunderstanding About the naming convention for bang methods. So, let me be clear:

1. Bang methods have absolutely nothing to do with mutation or destruction. It is simply about surprise. See the `Process::exit!` example above which has nothing to do with mutation.
2. Bang methods are always paired with a non-bang method. They mark the "more surprising" variant of a pair of methods. If there is no pair of methods, there is no bang. See, for example [`Array#collect!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-collect-21), which *does* have a bang because it is the more surprising variant of [`Array#collect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-collect), since it mutates its receiver; however, [`Array#append`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-append) does *not* have a bang even though it also mutates its receiver because there is no corresponding "less surprising" method.

> what "m.todo!" and "m.waiting!" are doing? I cannot understand if it is assigning a "true" value or a value that is the opposite of the current one like: m.todo = !m.todo

They do whatever the author of those methods wants. You will have to look that up in the documentation. Those are not methods of the Ruby core or standard library.

Comment: I’m not asking the behavior of the method itself, but the meaning if ! And ? . I know that I cannot asking you what they do :)